# eulerAngles reading is wrong between 90 and 270 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, euler-angles

I'm trying to rotate a light source between 8 stages, (including Sunrise, noon, etc.) The problem is that after it rotates through 270 (Going down) the value, read from the console, starts going up again and remains wrong until it reaches 90 when it once again gives the right one. The main bit of the code:

```
IEnumerator RotateLight()
{
    while (Mathf.Abs(transform.eulerAngles.x - angle) > 10f)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 1, Space.Self);
        yield return null;
    }
    yield break;
}
```

The problem is that although the sun looks as though it's rotating through the 'angle' (at which its supposed to stop) the console states otherwise (the console reading is the same as the one used to check when to stop or not).

As such, any 'angle' between 90 and 270 will cause my light source to spin eternally. Please help, I've looked everywhere and if someone else has had this problem, I don't see that they've received a solution.